# Regex in SSMS 2016

Tags: sql, regex, t-sql, ssms, ssms-2016

I am using ssms 2016. I have strings with following pattern `14Jan22_B_15May23_15_N_323_412_102`
I need to extract from it two things.

1. First number between two `_`. In this case it is 15, but it can be any number. I tried below method but it didn't work. it returns 0

```
DECLARE @InputString VARCHAR(MAX) = '14Jan22_B_15May23_15_N_323_412_102'; 
DECLARE @MatchPos INT = PATINDEX('%_[0-9]+_%', @InputString);
select @MatchPos
```

2. All numbers after `_N_` or `_R_`. Also this `_N_` or `_R_` needs to be after number from point 1. Because letter B can also be letter N.

I didn't start working on point 2, as I don't know how to resolve point 1

Comment: SSMS supports regex in it's find and replace feature, but that's it. You don't appear to be asking about SSMS here though, but T-SQL/SQL Server; SQL Server does *not* support Regex. SSMS is just an IDE-like application that is used with several products such as (but not limited to) SQL Server, Azure SQL Edge and Azure Synapse. SSMS is likely irrelevant to the question here. What product are you actually using for your data engine? Tagging [[tag:SSMS]] for your data engine is like tagging [[tag:visual-studio]] for your programming language; it doesn't actually really tell us anything.

Comment: `'%_[0-9]+_%'` in T-SQL's basic pattern matching means: 0+ characters (`%`) followed by any character (`_`), followed by any numerical character (`[0-9]`), followed by a plus character (`+`), followed by any character (`_`), followed by 0+ characters (`%`). As there are no plus (`+`) characters in your string, no patterns are found.

Comment: @ThomA Is there some way to define a pattern "Any number between _"?

Comment: You could possibly try something with string_split to split that string into rows, and then isnumeric on the output of that?

Comment: `TRY_CONVERT` to an `int` would make more sense than that [***awful***](https://wp.larnu.uk/stop-using-isnumeric-its-probably-wrong/) `ISNUMERIC` function, @Andrew .

Comment: Though, if the OP isn't on SQL  Server 2022 the `STRING_SPLIT` won't help either as you won't know which is the *first* integer value; the OP would have to use a UDF that returns the original position (such as `DelimitedSplit8k_LEAD`).

Comment: @ThomA - I'll blame the gremlins for making me think isnumeric instead of try_convert or try_cast. And I didn't notice the 2016 tag.

Comment: TBF, it's "SSMS 2016", a product that doesn't exist, @Andrew  (there was a SSMS in 2016, but it was called SSMS 16).

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong with your attempt that you may not catch right away. One of those issues is the `'_'` used in `'%_[0-9]+_%'` is a wildcard for a single character. The 2nd issue is that `15`, is not a number between 0 and 9, in which you have a single character search for a number `[0-9]`.

Maybe not the cleanest, but it works:

```
DECLARE @InputString VARCHAR(MAX) = '14Jan22_B_15May23_15_N_323_412_102'; 
DECLARE @MatchPos int = ISNULL(NULLIF(PATINDEX('%[_][0-9][_]%', @InputString),0),PATINDEX('%[_][0-9][0-9][_]%', @InputString))
DECLARE @num int = CHARINDEX('_N_',@InputString,@MatchPos)+3
DECLARE @t nvarchar(MAX) = SUBSTRING(@InputString,@num,LEN(@inputString)-@num)

;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT 
        REPLACE(LEFT(@t,CHARINDEX('_',@t)),'_','') [NUMBER], 
        CONCAT(REPLACE(@t,LEFT(@t,CHARINDEX('_',@t)),''),'_') [REMAINDER],  
        @t AS [Original Number After @num]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        REPLACE(LEFT([REMAINDER],CHARINDEX('_',[REMAINDER])),'_',''), 
        REPLACE([REMAINDER],LEFT([REMAINDER],CHARINDEX('_',[REMAINDER])),''), 
        @t
    FROM CTE 
    WHERE LEN([REMAINDER])>0
)
SELECT NUMBER AS [Ending Numbers] from CTE
SELECT @MatchPos [MatchPos index], REPLACE(substring(@InputString,@MatchPos,3),'_','') AS [MatchPos Number], @num [_N_ INDEX], SUBSTRING(@InputString,@num,LEN(@inputString)-@num) AS [Numbers After _N_]
```